# Get NewsFeed throws OAuthException

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get newsfeed from facebook using following code in MVC C#.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   JsonObject Data = new JsonObject();
   var fb = new FacebookClient("my_accesstoken");
   dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
   parameters.q = "SELECT created_time, updated_time, message, attachment, likes, share_count FROM stream WHERE filter_key in ( SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() ) AND created_time <= now() AND is_hidden=0"; 

   dynamic result = fb.Get("fql", parameters);

   retuen View();
}
```

on execution of this code it triggers OAuthException with following message

```
An exception of type 'Facebook.FacebookOAuthException' occurred in 
Facebook.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: (OAuthException - #606) (#606) Queries for 
these filter_keys: "nf,fl_1308485*******,fl_101358078*********,app_29151*******,app_2305********,
 app_23098*******,fl_11076123908*******,
 fl_1013580******,fl_110761242420941,fl_13084853*******,pp,app_239295*****,app_2347*******,app_23618*****" 
require a non-zero viewer that has granted read_stream permission
```

Any Help would be Apprieciated.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this API, but it looks like an app permissions error based on the output at the end of the exception. Have you read this: http://thepoliticsofsystems.net/2013/01/problematic-facebook-api-permissions-the-case-of-read_stream/